# Generate create to script from views

Tags: sql-server

I have source database where there are views. I want to `create to` tables script based on views structure on the other side in local sql server. When i right click on `create to` `new input window` it seems I cannot do it. Perhaps permission issue. Is there any option from code to get tables creation script?

Comment: *"Is there any option from code to get tables creation script?"* If you don't have permission to, no. You'll need to ask your DBA for permission; but if you don't have them you likely don't for a reason. (P.s. a `VIEW`and `TABLE` are completely different object; don't use the words interchangeably.)

Comment: funny thing is i can see fields and types when cehcking 'columns' - why the hell cannot generate script out of it ?

Comment: Of course you can, @Henry, you clearly have `SELECT`permission on the object.